# I have a new Netgear Router with a WD 1T external drive that I cannot see

Tags: networking, samba

I have a new Netgear R6200 Router. I have an external drive hooked up to it by the usb port. On my Windows computer I can see the drive and work with the files. On both of my Ubuntu 14.04 computers, I can see the Workgroup network but cannot access the drive or any other computers (which are all configured for sharing).

Answer (score 0):

Try with installing common WiFi drivers in ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Comment: Thank you. I believe that I downloaded the firmware, but as a newbie to Linux i am unaware of how to work with it. Would you help me out some more by pointing me in the right direction? Thank you

Comment: By the way, when I click on the Workgroup Icon and it tries to connect, I get this message:Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection timed out